# Get List items with a different user

Tags: development, web-part

I´m searching for a function in C# where I can open a Sharepoint List with a specific user. The user who runs the webpart have no permission for the SharePoint list. So my idea was to open the list with a admin user in the code behind.

Is there a possibility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check the SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges method to give user an admin privileged to the list.

[Impersonation in SharePoint](http://www.mssharepointtips.com/tip.asp?id=1022)

Answer (score 4):

```
Guid id = SPContext.Current.Site.ID;                
SPUser user = SPContext.Current.Web.EnsureUser("Loginname");              
  using (SPSite site = new SPSite(ID,user.UserToken))
   {
      using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
       { 
         //write code for further operation
       }
    }
```